# How to filter/reduce the data based on the latest date

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

```
data = {
 start: 1,
 data: [
  {
   name: 'Juan',
   date: '2020-01-19
  },
  {
   name: 'Carlo',
   date: '2020-03-01
  },
  {
   name: 'Dela',
   date: '2020-03-01
  },
  {
   name: 'Cruz',
   date: '2021-04-01
  }
 ],
 totalRecords: 19
}
```

What I'm trying to do filter the data to the latest date which is `2020-04-01`.

**What I tried is like this:**

```
response['data']['data'] = response['data']['data'].filter(item => {
           return item['date'] > '2020-04-01';
         });
```

But it doesn't work.

**Expected output** should be like this

```
data = {
 start: 1,
 data: [
  {
   name: 'Cruz',
   date: '2021-04-01
  }
 ],
 totalRecords: 19
}
```

Comment: do you wanna do  greater OR equal to instead? `return item['date'] >= '2020-04-01'`

Comment: `item['date'] > '2020-04-01';` ===> `item['date'] >= '2020-04-01';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers exist some problems (in terms of performance, expected output).

1. You shouldn't use `sort` because `time complexity` will take at least `O(nlogn)`.
2. Using `filter` will return *more than one* `lastItem`

*==>* So you can use `Array#reduce` (with time complexity is just `O(n)`) like this.

```js
const comparedDate = new Date('2020-04-01')
const response = {
 start: 1,
 data:[{name:'Juan',date:'2020-01-19'},{name:'Carlo',date:'2020-03-01'},{name:'Dela',date:'2020-03-01'},{name:'Cruz',date:'2021-04-01'}],
 totalRecords:19};

const lastData = response.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(new Date(curr.date) > comparedDate)
    acc = curr;
  
  return acc;
}, response.data[0]);

console.log(lastData);
```

**In case that you want to result in multiple items <= `2020-04-01`**, you can do like this

```js
const comparedDate = new Date('2020-04-01')
const response = {
 start: 1,
 data:[{name:'Juan',date:'2020-01-19'},{name:'Carlo',date:'2020-03-01'},{name:'Dela',date:'2020-03-01'},{name:'Cruz',date:'2021-04-01'}],
 totalRecords:19};

response.data = response.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(new Date(curr.date) >= comparedDate)
    acc.push(curr);
  
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: In that case, you can choose the second solution with the initialization data is an array` []);` @BeginnerCoder. Take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sort` and then take the first entry in the array to get the item with the latest date.

```
data.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))[0];
```

Comment: You shouldn't you `sort` because `time complexity` will take at least `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: With the updated post clarifying how output should be, disregard this answer. The other two answers accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the date strings into `Date` objects.

```js
const checkDate = new Date('2020-04-01')
const response = {
 start: 1,
 data: [
  {
   name: 'Juan',
   date: '2020-01-19'
  },
  {
   name: 'Carlo',
   date: '2020-03-01'
  },
  {
   name: 'Dela',
   date: '2020-03-01'
  },
  {
   name: 'Cruz',
   date: '2021-04-01'
  }
 ],
 totalRecords: 19
}

response.data = response
  .data
  .filter(({date}) => new Date(date) > checkDate)
  
console.log(response)
```